# An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services when adding or updating migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

I have downloaded one of my old projects and when I tried to run the `Update-Database` from the Package Manager Console I get the following message

> Build started... Build succeeded. An error occurred while accessing
> the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services. Continuing without the
> application service provider. Error: Value cannot be null. (Parameter
> 's') No DbContext was found in assembly 'BusinessLogicLayer'. Ensure
> that you're using the correct assembly and that the type is neither
> abstract nor generic.
> [image]

The difference between now and when I have used the application last time is that **I have reset windows**, and reinstalled all the programs back.

The application runs normally and I managed to add the migrations using

```
 CreateHostBuilder(args)
                     .Build()
                     .MigrateDatabase<DataContext>()
                     .Run();
```

and all tables have been created and populated with the seed data.
The last time I have been working on this project everything was working just fine.

This is how **I connect to the DB**

```
services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(optionsBuilder =>
                    optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql("User ID=postgres;Password=my_actual_pass;Server=localhost;Port=5432;Database=medication_platform3;Integrated Security=true;Pooling=true;"));
```

**Constructor** for DataContext

```
  public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options)
            : base(options) { }
```

**DataAccessLayer**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="Migrations\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="Migrations\**" />
    <None Remove="Migrations\**" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Migrations\20201207230245_InitialMigration.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Migrations\20201207230245_InitialMigration.Designer.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Migrations\DataContextModelSnapshot.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="5.0.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="6.8.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\BusinessObjectLayer\BusinessObjectLayer.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**appsettings.json**

```
{
  "JwtKey": "SOME_RANDOM_KEY_DO_NOT_SHARE",
  "JwtIssuer": "http://localhost:5001",
  "JwtExpireDays": 1,

  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

I can provide more information if needed.

Comment: There is a good chance that you appsettings file (or user secrets if you use them) are missing a curly brace somewhere, so some setting can't be read. Did you check this too? Also, how does your constructor for context looks like?

Comment: @NemanjaTodorovic, Yes, I did but I didn't find anything wrong. I have added my appsettings.json and the constructor for DataContext to my post now

Comment: Can you try to do update-database -verbose it could show you more detailed error?

Comment: @NemanjaTodorovic I managed to find the line causing the problem using  update-database -verbore, I will add an answer

Answer (score 1):

After using `update-database -verbose`

I was able to track the line with the problem.

```
   public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
                Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    int port = int.Parse(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PORT"));

                  ....
                }
```

This was a configuration made for the deployment and I forgot to change this line to

`int port= 5001`